# What is a solution( In visual studio)?

Tags: visual-studio

I read from MSDN that solutions "contain items that you need to create your application". What exactly does that mean? Does that mean it contains all the code that I need to create my application? If that's the case, why not just call it the application?

Comment: An "application" is a very vague term. Solutions contain (amongst others) projects which in turn contain source files. What is an application to you? The entire solution? A separate project? A combination of source files?

Comment: I think of an application as all the code, that when compiled, creates my application. Or all the code I need that successfully creates my application.

Comment: @Aldmeri Don't you realize you've got quite a problem with that definition? If application is the source code that creates the application, can that again be compiled to produce an application, that when compiled produces an application? So, what is an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why not just call it the application?

Because a solution can contain many applications, many supporting libraries used by those applications, various artifacts used for building and testing those applications.  A solution may even contain no application at all, just class library projects.

Think of a solution as a container for projects which are logically grouped in some way, as well as various artifacts which may be used by those projects.  A project in this case may be an application, a class library, a set of database scripts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is just container for projects, the idea is that different projects can share code thus be accessible easier than including outside libraries.

Comment: Okay, say we wanted to create an application that graphed mathematical functions and solved algebra. A solution will be all the code that does this for me? Or is the solution just all my projects? As in the project I just described, maybe another project that was a video game, and another project that was a bank application

Comment: @Aldmeri: If the business domain is math, I imagine a solution in that case would consist of class libraries used to perform mathematical functions and one or more applications used to interact with those class libraries.

Comment: Ah, okay I got it. Thanks a lot, David.